# How to make vim sessions use relative paths?

Tags: vim

I'm using such sessionopts:

```
set ssop=blank,buffers,sesdir,folds,localoptions,tabpages,winpos,winsize
```

The "sesdir" as opposed to "curdir" should store all the paths relative to the directory in which session file is located. Unfortunately there is a line in session file:

```
args absolute/path/to/file1 absolute/path/to/file2 and/so/on
```

How do I make vim use only relative paths so I could just put the session file into a git repo and resume my session from any machine?

Answer (score 1):

grosshat's solution doesn't work. Probably need to refer to  [Zsolt Botyaki's answer over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322908/force-vims-mksession-to-use-relative-paths):

> You can't do that without setting up a wrapper function for it, AFAIK.
>
> ```
> function! MakeSession()
>   let b:sessiondir = getcwd()
>   let b:filename = b:sessiondir . '/session.vim'
>   exe "mksession! " . b:filename
>   exe "edit! " . b:filename
>   exe "g:^cd :d"
>   exe "x" 
> endfunction
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange. When you set `sesdir` you declare the location of session will be set to be current working directory and all path in the session file will become **relative path** instead of absolute path.

I've used your sessionopts and it works. I can't find any line related to paths. How are you creating the session file? Standard is:

1. `:mksession [filename]`
2. vim -S [filename]